# How to create a Java function which Once called, cannot be called Again unless there is some DELAY?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a function which can ONLY be called again after there is some amount of time delay between the two calls, (Say 5 seconds).

I require this functionality for an android app I'm creating. 
Since it is possible that the user would be calling that function too frequently within a few seconds, it would destroy his experience. Hence, I'm desperately looking for an answer on this.

```
public void doSomethin(){
//code here which makes sure that this function has not been called twice within the specified delay of 5 seconds
//Some code here
}
```

Any help would be awesome!
Adit

Comment: dou you want a java program to excute every 5 secs ??

Comment: public syncronized void doSomethin()

Comment: @PC isn't synchronized just for thread safety?

Comment: yes, but it may achieve what he needs

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to make a singleton that bails if the timer hasn't expired.  But if you want something that can't be called, that's harder (and probably needlessly complicated depending on what you are trying to do).  I think we need more details before suggesting anything concrete.

Comment: i feel if you would just keep track of when the button was last pressed and compare that value to the now pressed..

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to simply disable the buttons after one has been clicked. Once the required action has been performed enable them again

Comment: No @Hussain I dont want it to run every 5 seconds.. The function is hooked to a gesture, and I dont want to execute the function within an interval of 5 second since its previous call!

Comment: @PowerPC Its a Gesture and Not a button that I can disable

Comment: public synchronized  void doSomething()
{
  this.sleep(5000);  // Please find the corresponding Android method
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could hold the time in milliseconds and check if the current time is greater than or equal to the previous time + 5 seconds. If it is, execute the method and replace the previous time with the current time.

See [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

```
public class FiveSeconds {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static long lastTime = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
            if(isValidAction()){
                System.out.println(input);
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else {
                System.out.println("You are not allowed to do this yet");
            }

            input = scanner.nextLine();
        }       
    }

    private static boolean isValidAction(){
        return(System.currentTimeMillis() > (lastTime + 5000));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but for an answer this simple, a few lines of Js would help someone who's new to the language more than that link

Comment: @Basic: You're correct, I have added a small example to showcase what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5):

If the code runs on your main thread, `Thread.sleep(5000)` is not an option. The easiest way to go then would be:

```
private long previous = 0;
public void doSomething() {
    long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    if (now - previous < 5000)
        return;

    previous = now;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, only thing I needed a change in my answer was the `previous = now` line needed to be in the if condition!

Comment: @AditGupta I doubt that, that would mean that if you call the function every second, the `do something` gets never executed.

Comment: NOPE! It means that as soon as the inner part of the if condition is run, I count that as the previous call. In your code if the person call the function every one secon , it will never run. In mine it will run every FIFTH time ( since >5000 ms)!!

Comment: Let's assume we start at time 0 and call this function every second. In my code:
Call 1: previous == 0, now == 1000 => return (previous not updated).
Call 2: previous == 0, now == 2000 => return (previous not updated).
...
Call 5: previous == 0, now == 5000 => previous = 5000; do something.

In your version:
Call 1: previous == 0, now == 1000 => previous = 1000; return.
Call 2: previous == 1000, now == 2000 => previous = 2000; return.
...
Call 5: previous == 4000, now == 5000 => previous = 5000; return.

So how is my code wrong?

Comment: Oh My Bad!!! I saw the (now-previous > 5000) instead of what you have written. Then I //do something inside the if condition!
Sorry Heuster! Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

use a static field, which saves the datetime of last execution and before executing check the current datetime against this timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write code for you but if you think a bit about this it's not that hard. You want to make sure it's not called before 5 seconds has passed since last function call. Let's split this into parts.

1) Get current time
2) Compare to stored time that keeps it value between calls.
3) If less than 5 seconds has passed don't do anything
4) Otherwise store the new value and do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you'll have to have a session level timer for *each and every user*.  This could be a fair amount of overhead depending on how many simultaneous users you have.

It's easy for one user: start a timer on request.  It's distinguishing between users that's the problem.  Your service is now stateful, which is usually a bad thing.  You're giving away idempotence.

You could also maintain state in a database.  Don't worry about calls; check persistent operations to make sure they don't happen too frequently.

It's not clear to me whether you mean to exclude all users for five seconds once the method is called by anyone, or if every user is prevented from calling the method again for five seconds once it's called the first time.

This sounds like a throughput killer.  I'd reconsider this design.

Answer (score 0):

I never did coding in Android. But if Android has threads (which is most likely, it does). Then within this function sleep the thread for 5 seconds, it means even though it is called, it won't be executed further until 5 seconds are passed

```
public void doSomething()
{
  Thread.sleep(5000);  // Please find the corresponding Android method
}
```

Comment: Unless the method is synchornized, multiple threads can invoke this parallely

Comment: You need to be careful on Android as you shouldn't sleep the main thread giving you an unresponsive application.

Answer (score 0):

make `doSomethin()` as a private method.

Expose another function say exposedDoSomething().

```
public void exposeDoSomething(){

   // Add to a queue

}
```

In a separate thread read the queue in every 5 mins and call `doSomethin()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a TimerTask will help you, more details here:

[TimerTask|Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Example:

```
    private TimerTask tiemrTast= new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {


    }
};
```

And then use this method: `public void scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use hander.postDalayed method to call method to run after specific delay
you can use your method something like this

```
int delay=5000;
int k;
int iDelayTimeInMiliSeconds=2000;
                    for( k=0;k<arrBatch.size();k++)
                    {           
                        delay=delay+iDelayTimeInMiliSeconds;
                        callAllDocumentList(arrBatch.get(k),k,delay);                               
                    }   


public void callAllDocumentList(final String strInvoiceId,final int count,int delay) 
{
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {   
               // call your function here that you want to call after specific delay
            //getOrderDetails(strInvoiceId,count,true);

        }
    }, delay);
}
```